# How to add rel nofollow in these links in magento? for example "Add to Compare"

Tags: magento, nofollow

How to add rel nofollow at these links in magento store? Thanks in advance.

in product page,
"Add to compare"
"Add to wishlist"
"email to your friends"
"reviews"
"Add your review"
"Sign up for price alert"
"social bookmark share"

in checkout page,
"Terms and Conditions"
"Already registered? Click here to login."

We take a autoradio online store website a example in this case.
http://www.onlyforcars.com/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Find the template file that generates the add to compare link and put it in there.

Comment: could you please tell me more detail.thanks in advance. which path in template file.:)

Comment: Depending on your version of Magento it could vary, but in the install I am looking at right now it is located in the /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view/addto.phtml file

Comment: Keep in mind that the template you are using could be overriding that file, etc. It should be in a path similar to that though.

Comment: Josh,Thanks so much,in product page it is okay.i am trying to modify other.thanks again.Josh V5... :)

Comment: but i try to modify "email to your friends",it does work.what's wrong? and "add to cart","add to compare"on the home page still be not changed.Josh,Could you please help me again.it is better to list all the paths.Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://www.westwideweb.com/wp/2009/08/04/magento-how-to-turn-on-template-path-hints-and-inline-translation/ This will show you how to turn on template path hints. That will tell you where all the files are for each part of a page. Try this to see if that helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Josh,SOS...pls help me.some error happen."Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/xxxx/public_html/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/new.phtml on line 37".Hot to modify it.Thanks in advance.

Comment: there have a messy code              " <h3 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_product->getName()) ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape(Mage::helper('core/string')->truncate($_product->getName(),60,'鈥?)); ?></a></h3>"

Comment: Once you have gotten an answer on SO you should check the green check box by the answer to let people know that the solution worked for you. This will help other people that fall into the same situation as you.